# Parent controllers Nokia lumia 520

Tags: parental-control

I am trying to set up the Microsoft account on my daughter's Nokia Lumia 520. There is a prompt that I need to OK it as her parent. I do this, using my Microsoft account, but it says my name or date of birth are incomplete. I have accessed my account and verified that they are complete. Does anyone know what else I can do??

Comment: Have you run through [these instructions on setting up 'My Family'](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/apps/my-family-on-the-windows-phone-website) on the Windows Phone website?

Comment: try http://familysafety.microsoft.com/

Comment: Yes , but the settings are very complicated.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your problem and more is covered in this article http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/apps/my-family-on-the-windows-phone-website